# how to change sender name with facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, token

hi I use facebook application and I want send feed message to page wall

```
$accesstokens = 'blalbalba';
$post =  array(
        'access_token' => $accesstokens,
        'message' => 'This message auto created - ' . date('d/m/Y H:i:s')
    );
```

I try everythin from , to ,user

I try graph api explorer

when I try send message with token

facebook api add extra this code to message

```
"application": {
    "name": "Application name", 
    "namespace": "application_namespace", 
    "id": "app id"
  },
```

but I try send message normally from facebook and this code not in there
only adding this code try facebook api

and I see the application name on wall message "Share by Application"

How I change this ? I create page and when I try send message with facebook api and I sending message but I dont want see application name on my page wall

Comment: What are you posting to, a user or a page timeline? For a user timeline, you can not achieve this – your app will always be shown as the one the post was made with. When you post to a page _as_ the page, then this information is not shown. (FYI, you are not allowed to post automated messages to user timelines.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like CBroe says in his comment, you are not allowed to auto-post any content, or use pre-filled comments/messages/captions. This is explained in [Facebook's policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

There is also no way to remove app attribution data when creating content from an app. This is regardless of what SDK you are using. Even if you don't use an SDK, but only the Graph API, your content will contain app attribution data.